# What type of conifer is this and is it OK near a house?

Tags: identification, conifers

I need help identifying this conifer. Also, it is standing really close to a house (about 6-8 feet, some 2 meters). Can its root systems be harmful to the foundation or sewer line (which by the way is close by)? It is about as high as a 2-story house.

Tree: [image: tree]
Leaves: [image: close-up on the leaves]

Comment: It reminds me of *Chamaecyparis nootkatensis* 'Green Arrow'.

Answer (score 1):

In 50 years it may be a concern for falling on the house. Unfortunately I left many large ( 3 ft. diameter/ 100 ft tall) southern pines close to house and garage when I built 25 years ago. Several are less than 10 ft away. No problems with the roots . The main problem is sleeping nights when there is a windstorm.